# How do I get EditText floating label to float before OnFocusChangeListeners updates UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have and EditText with a floating label that does not float the text hint until after the listener launches and closes (dismisses) a dialogfragment. I am trying to have the hint float right after the EditText gains focus, and before the dialogfragment is launched, so the user can see the completed hint floated.  The EditText uses "hasFocus" code that appears to be preventing the label from floating right away, although it eventually does after the diaglogfragment is closed. It seems the OnFocusChangeListener gains priority over the TextInoutLayout floating label on the UI thread, not sure why. Please advise.

Activity.java

```
    ....
    private ListenerEditText fListenerEditText;
    fListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(R.id.FEditText);
    fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()      {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, final boolean hasFocus) {
           if(hasFocus) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
       }
    }
    }); 
    ...
```

layout file.xml
        ...

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/DueDate_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="0">

    <com.example.jdw.thirdscreen.ListenerEditText
    android:id="@+id/FEditText"
    android:hint="Due Date"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|start"
    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="51"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"  >

    </com.example.jdw.thirdscreen.ListenerEditText>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extend TextInputLayout and add interface for listetning when label is done floating.

Source code should be located somewhere around here:

```
<android-sdk>\sdk\extras\android\support\design\libs
```

Comment: I am a newcomer to android and java programming...can you give me a basic code example of extending TextInputLayout and add interface for listening?  Also, how will looking at source code help me?  because I can see the priority for how the UI screen is updated?